# How can I play a video file from a Resource?

Tags: android

I am trying to get a video to pop up and play. I can get it to work when I use the first URI (that is commented out in the below code), but when I try to use the second URI (from the resource), I get the following error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1052): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { dat=android.resource://com.slamdunksoftware.presentation/2130968576 typ=video/* }
```

From researching the error, it looks like I might have to declare an activity in the manifest but I'm not sure if that applies here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/page4a.m4v");        
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.slamdunksoftware.presentation/" + R.raw.page4a);

in.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
startActivity(in);
```

Comment: You may want to reword this as "How can I play a video file from a Resource?" The ActivityNotFound exception is a bit of a red herring here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to declare anything in your manifest. You only declare your own `Activities` in the manifest file. In the case above, you are trying to play a video and relying on the OS to provide a program to do so. As you just experienced, not all devices (or emulators) have an app for playing video. So, the best you can do here is creating your own `Activity` to play videos:

[How to play video and audio on Android](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Any ideas why it would work for the first case (the commented out uri) but not in the second?

Comment: Because no intent filters in the system recognize the URI scheme (android.resource://) you're using in the second case.